# Get the last name of a directory path in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I've been tasked with writing installation scripts for my company that will be able to install printer drivers on a users computer.

What I have done so far is I've made the script accept a parameter (the printer type brother, xerox, etc..) from there it will gather the relative path to the drivers, and run a `forfiles` command on the path outputting all the drivers, after that it will ask the user for the correct driver copy it from the network drive to the users desktop, and run it.

What I need to do is the running part, I need to copy the driver to the desktop and somehow get the last directory part (example: `user\desktop\test.exe` I need to  gather the last part `test.exe`) how can I go about doing this in a functional way?

Basically I would need to split the path by `\` and grab the last entry of that list, is this possible in batch?

```
@echo off

type banner.txt

if [%1]==[] goto usage

:verify_argv
    IF '%1'=='canon' GOTO get_canon_path
    IF '%1'=='xerox' GOTO get_xerox_path
    IF '%1'=='hp' GOTO get_hp_path
    IF '%1'=='dell' GOTO get_dell_path
    IF '%1'=='brother' GOTO get_brother_path
    goto :eof

:get_canon_path
    set dir_path=\\mgtutils01\windows7apps\PRINTERS\Canon
    goto :install_drivers

:get_xerox_path
    set dir_path=\\mgtutils01\windows7apps\PRINTERS\Xerox
    goto :install_drivers

:get_hp_path
    set dir_path=\\mgtutils01\windows7apps\PRINTERS\HP
    goto :install_drivers

:get_dell_path
    set dir_path=\\mgtutils01\windows7apps\PRINTERS\Dell
    goto :install_drivers

:get_brother_path
    set dir_path=\\mgtutils01\windows7apps\Brother\Drivers
    goto :install_drivers

:usage
    @echo Usage: .\driver [PRINTER_TYPE]
    exit /B 1

:install_drivers
    @echo Finding drivers...
    pushd "%dir_path%"
    forfiles /s /m *.exe /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"
    set /p to_install="Copy the path of the correct driver and paste here: "
    @echo Copying file to %USERPROFILE%, please wait..
    xcopy %to_install% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
    @echo Installing driver..
    pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
```

Comment: No need for `FORFILES`.  A normal `FOR` command with the `/R` option will run faster.

Comment: Seems like it would be simpler and cleaner to just set the path to the driver within the execution of the `IF` command. `IF '%1'=='canon' set dir_path=\\mgtutils01\windows7apps\PRINTERS\Canon`

Comment: And you might want to consider making your string comparisons case insensitive by using the `/I` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last element of a file or directory path, you can:

1. either use a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and its `~` modifiers:

   ```cmd
   set "ITEM=user\desktop\test.exe"
   for %%I in ("%ITEM%") do set "NAME=%%~nxI"
   echo %NAME%
   ```
2. or call a sub-routine by the [`call` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html), pass the path as an argument and again use `~` modifiers:

   ```cmd
   set "ITEM=user\desktop\test.exe"
   call :SUB "%ITEM%"
   goto :EOF

   :SUB
   set "NAME=%~nx1"
   goto :EOF
   ```

For both variants, the `~nx` part extracts the base name (`n`) and the extension (`x`) from the last element of the path stored in the reference (`%%I` or `%1`). Type `for /?` and `call /?` into a command prompt window and read the help texts; you will find all the possible `~` modifiers of `for` variable references and argument references, respectively.